# Should be a simple answer to YOY SQL Calc

Tags: sql

I have several years of data I am looking at the current previous 15 days using:

```
DATE_ADD(`date_entered`, interval -15 day)
```

Now what I want is to find the same 15 days from 1 year ago. By using:

```
SUM(CASE 
WHEN DAYOFYEAR(`date_entered`,0) = DAYOFYEAR(DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL -15 day),0)  
THEN ('Rev') 
ELSE 0
END)
```

My syntax looks to be good, but it isn't displaying any results. I hate Period over Period calc. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your syntax looks very database specific.

Comment: A `SUM` will always produce a result (null or 0 or otherwise) for each group (or each row with window functions).  Not displaying any results has something to do with logic you didn't show.  Can you provide a complete `SELECT` statement and corresponding data that should produce results, but does not?  Make the test case as simple as possible, yet still produce the behavior of interest.

Answer (score 0):

To try and evaluate your 15 day period in the CASE block try to work out from my code example here.

This is for MS-SQL

```
DECLARE 
    @old_date date = '2001/01/25'
    , @new_date date = '2001/02/1'

SELECT DATEDIFF( day, @old_date, @new_date)

    ,CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF( day, @old_date, @new_date) <= 15 THEN 'TRUE'
            ELSE 'FALSE'
        END AS xxx
```